# Generating columns in ObjectListView C#

Tags: c#, objectlistview

In normal ListView I usually generate columns on fly with something like:

```
        var list = new List<ColumnNameSize>();
        list.Add(new ColumnNameSize("Computer Name", 0));
        list.Add(new ColumnNameSize("Full Computer Name", 150));
        list.Add(new ColumnNameSize("Migrated", 150));
        list.Add(new ColumnNameSize("Disabled", 0));
        list.Add(new ColumnNameSize("Disabled & Not Migrated", 150));
        generateListView(listViewObjects, list);

        public static void generateListView(ListView varListView, List<ColumnNameSize> nameSizeList) {
        varListView.ClearColumns();
        foreach(ColumnNameSize nameSize in nameSizeList) {
            varListView.AddColumn(nameSize.ColumnName, nameSize.ColumnSize);
        }
    }
```

How would I do it in [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). I've tried multiple combinations:

```
    public void generateListView(ObjectListView varListView, List<ColumnNameSize> nameSizeList) {

        ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (ColumnNameSize nameSize in nameSizeList) {
            OLVColumn columnHeader = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn();  
            columnHeader.Width = nameSize.ColumnSize;
            columnHeader.Text = nameSize.ColumnName;
            myArrayList.Add(columnHeader);
            varListView.AllColumns.Add(columnHeader);
        }
        Object columnsHeader = myArrayList.ToArray();
        varListView.Columns.AddRange( columnsHeader);
    }
```

But none seems to work...

Comment: Seems like you are adding columns twice; once from `AllColumns.Add()` and then again with `Columns.AddRange()`

Comment: I know, this is what i tried ... I did it with .Add and it didn't show up.. so i tried with AddRange but it expects OLVColumn[] and not object.

Comment: Instead of `Columns.AddRange()` call `RebuildColumns()` to rebuild them from `AllColumns`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
 public void generateListView(ObjectListView varListView, List<ColumnNameSize> nameSizeList) {

        List<OLVColumn>  columnsList = new List<OLVColumn>();
        foreach (ColumnNameSize nameSize in nameSizeList) {
            OLVColumn columnHeader = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn();  
            columnHeader.Width = nameSize.ColumnSize;
            columnHeader.Text = nameSize.ColumnName;
            columnsList .Add(columnHeader);
            varListView.AllColumns.Add(columnHeader);
        }
        varListView.Columns.AddRange( columnsList.Cast<System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader>().ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: It works .. but only if i add one column manually in IDE and then execute this. Then it adds more columns. If i remove the column from IDE and just use this it doesn't show up. It seems there must be some setting that enables showing headers.. It might be that it worked all along with first tries...

Comment: I modified it slightly based on usage from the usage in this page http://www.assembla.com/code/deskblog/git/nodes/ObjectListView/Tests/MainForm.Designer.cs?rev=79c9b6fd3b29de9b696d6879508fe0a7d11e04ec see if it helps otherwise I have no other idea. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: It works tnx. Just need to find out how to "show" headers now :-) The whole idea behind this you did works just fine. So don't delete. It's just I'm probably missing some setting to show it.

Comment: It started working after I added some data into it. So tnx a lot.

Comment: ObjectListView looks very interesting but doesn't seem like it's well documented.

Comment: Ye it has some basic tutorial assuming most people will understand how to achieve what they want. It also give some heavy examples with all code but other then that you're on your own. But seeing from screenshots it's amazing.

Answer (score 1):

To make the columns visible after adding them manually through code, you need to rebuild them with the following line:

```
varListView.RebuildColumns();
```

Based on Bala's answer, you get the following code:

```
public void generateListView(ObjectListView varListView, List<ColumnNameSize> nameSizeList)
{
    List<OLVColumn> columnsList = new List<OLVColumn>();
    foreach (ColumnNameSize nameSize in nameSizeList)
    {
        OLVColumn columnHeader = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn();
        columnHeader.Width = nameSize.ColumnSize;
        columnHeader.Text = nameSize.ColumnName;
        columnsList.Add(columnHeader);
        varListView.AllColumns.Add(columnHeader);
    }

    varListView.Columns.AddRange(columnsList.Cast<System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader>().ToArray());
    varListView.RebuildColumns();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ObjectListView to work as intended, you have to define the name of the desired property of your model object as AspectName.

Instead of first creating a list of ColumnNameSize, I'd rather add the columns one by one:

```
ObjectListView1.AllColumns.Add(new OLVColumn()
{
    Text = "Column Header",
    Width = 100,
    AspectName = "myProperty"
});

ObjectListView1.RebuildColumns();
```